# How Insert two table

Tags: php, mysql

i already write code like this:

```
$password = md5($password);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,email,pnum,hintque,hintans) VALUES('$username','$password','$email','$cnum','$hintque','$hintans')");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `personal` (userid,fname,lname,address,dob,country,state,city,poscode) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$fname','$lname','$address','$dob','$country','$state','$city'.'$zip')");
            header("location: ../register.php?feedback=Registration Complete. You May Now Login");
```

but only first sql success to insert data. for the second one fail.
i want both query triggered on the same time.

Comment: ... ,'$city'.'$zip') comma missing

Comment: don't use the deprecated mysql library...

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: $mysqli->multi_query($sql)

Comment: *sidenote:* MD5 is unsafe for hashing password. Use mcrypt libraries instead.

Answer (score 5):

The second query likely fails because you a have syntax error (see last value, `.` should be `,`):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `personal` (userid,fname,lname,address,dob,country,state,city,poscode) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$fname','$lname','$address','$dob','$country','$state','$city','$zip')");
```

Also, please avoid using `mysql_*`. That family of functions is now deprecated, and you should be using something more up-to-date such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `personal` (userid,fname,lname,
             address,dob,country,
             state,city,poscode) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$fname','$lname',
        '$address','$dob','$country',
        '$state','$city','$zip')");
```

**Problem :**

`'$city'.'$zip'` is `'$city','$zip'`

**Note** : `mysql_*` functions is now deprecated now. Try to use `mysqli`

Comment: You're not telling the OP **what** he's doing wrong. You're merely stating the correct code.

Comment: @RichardA I am writing step by step.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have two things happen at the same time in a script. Nearly at the same time might be possible. But usually that is not really the goal. Instead take a look at a construct called `transactions` offered by all serious database management systems. It allows you to combine a series of sql statements to a single unit that either succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [**mysqli_multi_query**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)